# C# .net core in docker JWT Authorize error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, bearer-token

Needs ensure authorize to .net Core web api in docker via JWT Bearer

In my Startup.cs:

```
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  var pem = File.ReadAllText("publickey.pem");
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pem);

  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(bytes)
      };
    });

    services.AddMvc();
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
  }
...
```

My publickey.pem looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
JBkjgkVBJKlgkljvk.jgk;4jkgJLBjkgJHcvbnVBcCghfb+dfdFdf5fdf54ASfG5
Sov1MTHDHZHORsZgWQKTbmfv/BjsgdfbvKJGuklVhjklTuiltgjkgtJKLgJKLTUG
diGauBf4HfFZP/iJZq43cuPXKXRRhX8Xp/3FGZ1HL4FRiXdAnoPuY/ofBclXEIUM
XWpJcBdN4pUiV2sCFDDMx6+KDl69orsfIwHnX3trjIeSJX7RWJyBOI8A1PJmeYFJ
T9Paq5qFdxxF6udNoxhZN5kTTmCqZTLesQf3mk1HLj759ZS8E1NlxoXWS3h8D3jd
SHesaEltPlrdA/y3rRa84OrwyryLp9kh8IOYXIifXPyeP1RWP2bGDkBcHiSyzgr/
cwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And my controller:

```
[Route("check")]
public class CheckController : ReqController {
  [HttpGet, Authorize]
  public Response Task() {
    try {
      token = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
      DB.Check();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      response.Status = e.Message;
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

Calling my api via Postman:
I chose `GET` method. On `Authorization` tab chose `Bearer Token` and inserted my Token

After send request in response headers I receive:

```
Content-Length →0
Date →Wed, 06 Jun 2018 08:01:02 GMT
Server →Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

On site https://jwt.io/ I've also check my Token (RSASHA256) with public key that I have and there is show me `Signature Verified`

Where I could make a mistake or something I could have missed?

Comment: Can you try to encode it via Base64 instead of ASCII?

Comment: @Progressive via Convert.FromBase64String? 
If yes that error on start: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'

Comment: I suspect that File.ReadAllText and copying the text do not capture the same string somehow. Can you watch your "pem" variable if it is filled with the correct value?

Comment: @Progressive I think problem with token, It was encoded with rs256, but jwt core support only HS256/384/512 algorithms

Comment: I think you will find your answer here http://piotrgankiewicz.com/2017/07/24/jwt-rsa-hmac-asp-net-core/
It explains your problem

Comment: running into same issue, it doesn't work when containerized. See my question on https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/877 maybe they might find a solution there.